# How to insert Value from JSON Data into table

Tags: python, json, psycopg2

I have a JSON Data,

```
[[{'Design Project': 'Not Available',
   'Design Target*': 'Not Available',
   'Median Property*': '50',
   'Metric': 'ENERGY STAR score (1-100)'},
  {'Design Project': 'Not Available',
   'Design Target*': '35.4',
   'Median Property*': '141.4',
   'Metric': 'Source EUI (kBtu/ftÂ²)'},
  {'Design Project': 'Not Available',
   'Design Target*': '15.8',
   'Median Property*': '63.1',
   'Metric': 'Site EUI (kBtu/ftÂ²)'},
  {'Design Project': 'Not Available',
   'Design Target*': '3,536.0',
   'Median Property*': '14,144.1',
   'Metric': 'Source Energy Use (kBtu)'},
  {'Design Project': 'Not Available',
   'Design Target*': '1,578.7',
   'Median Property*': '6,314.9',
   'Metric': 'Site Energy Use (kBtu)'},
  {'Design Project': 'Not Available',
   'Design Target*': '34.61',
   'Median Property*': '138.44',
   'Metric': 'Energy Cost ($)'},
  {'Design Project': '0.0',
   'Design Target*': '0.2',
   'Median Property*': '0.6',
   'Metric': 'Total GHG Emissions (Metric Tons CO2e)'}],
 [{'Energy Type': ['Energy Not Entered',
                   'Assumed Mix Based on State & Property Type:',
                   '',
                   'Electric - Grid (56.9%)',
                   'Natural Gas (43.1%)'],
   'Target': ' Target % Better than Median: 75',
   'Title': "About this Property's Design",
   'Uses:': 'Other - Education (100.0%)'}],
 [{'Your Design Score ': ' N/A'}]]
```

I want to remove the Key from the Json because in my Postgres table, key is my column. I want to insert the value to my column.

I would like to do it using Python.

Comment: What is the Key?

Comment: For  example Metric is one key

Comment: So, do you want to data to look something like this? ['ENERGY STAR score (1-100)',  'Not Available', ...]

Comment: @DheerajNair yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def f(l_of_l_of_ds):
    return [list(l2.values())
            for l1 in l_of_l_of_ds
            for l2 in l1]
```

Which yields:

```
[['Not Available', 'Not Available', '50', 'ENERGY STAR score (1-100)'],
 ['Not Available', '35.4', '141.4', 'Source EUI (kBtu/ftÂ²)'],
 ['Not Available', '15.8', '63.1', 'Site EUI (kBtu/ftÂ²)'],
 ['Not Available', '3,536.0', '14,144.1', 'Source Energy Use (kBtu)'],
 ['Not Available', '1,578.7', '6,314.9', 'Site Energy Use (kBtu)'],
 ['Not Available', '34.61', '138.44', 'Energy Cost ($)'],
 ['0.0', '0.2', '0.6', 'Total GHG Emissions (Metric Tons CO2e)'],
 [['Energy Not Entered',
   'Assumed Mix Based on State & Property Type:',
   '',
   'Electric - Grid (56.9%)',
   'Natural Gas (43.1%)'],
  ' Target % Better than Median: 75',
  "About this Property's Design",
  'Other - Education (100.0%)'],
 [' N/A']]
```